# adb install apk by code using command

Tags: android

i want to install app by command,because my app have many apks,and i have root,i want to install apk by command:

public static void installApp(){

```
String cmd="adb install /mnt/sdcard/ClockApp.apk";
   try{  

          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 
          p.waitFor();

     }  catch(IOException t)  {  
           t.printStackTrace();  
      } catch(InterruptedException t)  {  
           t.printStackTrace();  
      }
  }
```

but the code not effect. and app not give mistake.can you gime some advice?

Comment: wat's the exception or error occuring?

Answer (score 0):

**Using Command line**

You can use the code below to install application from command line

> adb install example.apk

this apk is installed in the internal memory of current opened emulator.

> adb install -s example.apk
>   this apk is installed in the sd-card of current opened emulator

**Using Program**

```
Process p = null;
try
{
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outs=new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());

    String cmd="pm install /mnt/sdcard/ClockApp.apk";
    outs.writeBytes(cmd+"\n");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: why is pm install at "pm install /mnt/sdcard/ClockApp.apk";

Comment: It's not, that is the command string.  The program being run is probably something like /system/bin/pm or similar, and (hopefully) already in the path, otherwise you'll have to find it and explicitly give the full path.

Comment: how to find the full path？

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Digital Alchemist, make sure you input the code `adb install example.apk` in the terminal inside of you platform-tools folder.

Comment: The poster is trying to issue the command from code on the device itself, not from a connected ADB host.